# E-mail PTR failure - Spamcannibal

Tags: email, spam, isp

My IP is on Spamcannibal list. So I can't communicate with my registered partners. To be precise I can't send e-mail to only two domain. Everything else is ok.

I try to talk with my domain/server hosting company, try to talk with the Spamcannibal and try to talk with the e-mail administrators,

...but now i'm totally lost.

Something's wrong with my PTR record, but I really don't understand what I should do now.

Who's business is this?:

- Do I have to talk with my ISP? (I use two different ISPs, home / work )
- or the domain/server provider? (Ipage)
- or should I talk again e-mail administrator of that e-mails which did not work
- or should I talk again to Spamcannibal?

The error message that I get back after send an e-mail:

host mail27.indamail.hu [91.83.45.27]: 550 5.1.1  recipient rejected, your address, **50.92.189.3**  is listed in spamcannibal.org

My ip is sometimes: 50.92.189.6 or the end is 10.

Comment: The IPs you mentioned are on no DNSBL at all.

Answer (score 0):

1. none of the mentioned IPs has a proper A record (dXXX-XXX-XXX-XXX.telus.net is not such a record in most cases)
2. There is no MX record for any of the mentioned IPs
3. Not even trying to check for SPF or DK records...

Conclusion - you don't have an MTA set up in DNS at all, so you cannot expect to be able to send emails in a normal fashion. You need to either purchase a domain name, set up an MX and other records and get to work, or use a registered smarthost (ask your ISP for that)

Comment: The above IP address changed for this example, because i don't know if a security issue if i tell my IP.

Comment: well if you want to hide your IP, just hide it, don't provide someone else's IP instead. Anyway, the only way to get out of an RBL is to check why you got there, fix the issue, and contact the RBL maintainers asking to remove you from their listings. The instructions are on spamcannibal.org

Comment: I just type ip randomly..

Comment: My hosting provider answer: PTR record is not supported in shared hosting. hence, it is not possible to add PTR record on our servers.

Comment: well, if you have no PTR, other MTAs cannot run a PTR test for your MX, and in most cases, PTR is the first among many tests. I would start looking into changing the hosting provider, to one that allows you to manage DNS as you need

Answer (score 0):

The reverse lookup (PTR) for those IP addresses returns a "generic" DNS name:

```
dig +short -x 50.92.189.3  : d50-92-189-3.bchsia.telus.net.
dig +short -x 50.92.189.6  : d50-92-189-6.bchsia.telus.net.
dig +short -x 50.92.189.10 : d50-92-189-10.bchsia.telus.net.
```

The guys at Spamcannibal list IP addresses that match these "generic" patterns and are quite adamant that they won't de-list them.  You have a few options:

1. Talk to your ISP and have them change your PTR records.
2. Talk to your ISP and start using their smart host.
3. Change ISP.

Listing IP addresses that match these patterns is not all that uncommon in DNSBLs and you will find you have a lot of trouble sending mail from these IP addresses.